# In Solr search multiple objects not updated

Tags: solr, solr4

In `solr` search multiple objects are not updated or inserted. Please help me.

```
"materialNames":[
                                {
                                "material_id":1,
                                "description":"Motor Oil",
                                "business":"",
                                "residential":"",
                                "notes":""
                                },
                                {
                                "material_id":2,
                                "description":"Oil Filters",
                                "business":"",
                                "residential":"",
                                "notes":""
                                }
                            ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to insert Embedded document into Solr

*Note that:*

*1> I have used `Solr 4.7.0`*

*2> I have referred [Embedded Documents In Solr](http://www.solrfromscratch.com/2014/08/20/embedded-documents-in-solr/) you can follow the steps mentioned in this.*

**OR**

Below are the steps

### Step 1:

Create a lib folder in your solrhome folder( which has `bin` and `collection1` folders)

Add below jar files to lib folder

```
- solrjsonchild-0.0.1.jar
- json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

You can get `solrjsonchild-0.0.1.jar` file from [source code](http://www.solrfromscratch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/solrjsonchild.zip)(convert it into jar) or [here](http://www.solrfromscratch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/solr-4.9.0-MODIFIED.zip)(**path:**`/solr-4.9.0-MODIFIED.zip/solr-4.9.0/contrib/solrjsonchild-0.0.1.jar`)

### Step 2:

On `solrconfig.xml`

modify

```
 <requestHandler name="/update"  class="com.solrfromscratch.handler.UpdateModifiedRequestHandler">
```

modify

```
<requestHandler name="/update/json" class="com.solrfromscratch.handler.UpdateModifiedRequestHandler">
```

### Step 3:

On `schema.xml`

- *Define* `<fieldType name="json" class="com.solrfromscratch.fields.Json"/>`
- *Configure your field* `<field name="materialNames_json" type="json" indexed="false" stored="true"/>`
- *Configure a dynamic field* `<dynamicField name="materialNames.*" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`

**Note:** Embedded field name sholud be end with `_json` otherwise it will throw error `Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START`

### Step 4:

Run Solr (I have used port `8973`)

update json document

```
{"id":"123",
"materialNames_json":[
                            {
                            "material_id":1,
                            "description":"Motor Oil",
                            "business":"",
                            "residential":"",
                            "notes":""
                            },
                            {
                            "material_id":2,
                            "description":"Oil Filters",
                            "business":"",
                            "residential":"",
                            "notes":""
                            }
                  ] }
```

**Result:**

`http://localhost:8973/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true`

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 0,
"params": {
  "indent": "true",
  "q": "*:*",
  "_": "1426163321444",
  "wt": "json"
 }
},
"response": {
"numFound": 1,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "123",
    "materialNames.0.residential": "",
    "materialNames.0.description": "Motor Oil",
    "materialNames.0.material_id": "1",
    "materialNames.0.notes": "",
    "materialNames.0.business": "",
    "materialNames.1.residential": "",
    "materialNames.1.description": "Oil Filters",
    "materialNames.1.material_id": "2",
    "materialNames.1.notes": "",
    "materialNames.1.business": "",
    "materialNames_json": [
      {
        "residential": "",
        "description": "Motor Oil",
        "material_id": 1,
        "notes": "",
        "business": ""
      },
      {
        "residential": "",
        "description": "Oil Filters",
        "material_id": 2,
        "notes": "",
        "business": ""
      }
    ],
    "_version_": 1495440547544825900
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

Hope this helps.